# SQL query to identify records not IN set

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am inserting rows into a table. I have the **Program_ID, Trip_ID, P_username** basically all candidate keys to uniquely identify any record.

I will be setting selected = 1 on new rows inserted, but at the same time I wish to set selected to 0 on all rows in the table that do not match that **Program_ID and Trip_ID** combination.

How can I accomplish this in 1 query and preferably with active record.?

In this case new participants are **Mike3, Andy2**

```
 foreach( $all_participants as $single_participant )
{

 $this->db->insert('Itinerary', $single_participant);


}
```

### Psuedo code

```
 Select Selected from Itinerary
where Program_ID ! = $current_program ID and Trip_ID != $current_trip_id
set selected = '0';
```

### Itinerary Table:

```
---------------------------------------------
| Program_ID | Trip_ID |P_Username|Selected |
---------------------------------------------
| f33r3      | F3231   | Andy2    | 1       |  <- new row selected = 1
---------------------------------------------
| f33r3      | F3231   | Mike3    | 1       |  <- new row selected = 1
---------------------------------------------
| YUAd4      | F3231   | Jane12   | 1       |  <- old row set selected = 0
---------------------------------------------
| Hl341      | F3231   | Mike44   | 0       |  <- Keep at 0
--------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You can't INSERT and UPDATE at the same time. You could set a trigger to UPDATE the old records every time a new one is INSERTed

Comment: @mikeW I think that's a good idea i will look into triggers